# PHPExcel verify if cell has empy value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpexcel

Hello i have an import of an xls file with multiple rows on it and i want to insert them into database only if the price columns has a value different than nothing else display an error msg. It works on half it only inserts those rows that have a value for price but instead returning the html error msg it returns the sql msg, that means it goes on the else branch.
Here is my code

```
$exceldata = array();

$uploadFilePath = 'uploads/'.basename($_FILES['doc']['name']);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['doc']['tmp_name'], $uploadFilePath);

        $inputfilename = 'uploads/'.$_FILES['doc']['name'].'';
//  Read your Excel workbook
try
{
    $inputfiletype = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputfilename);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputfiletype);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputfilename);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputfilename,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}

//  Get worksheet dimensions
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

$header=$_POST['membership'];

if($header==1)
{
//  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++)
{ 

    //  Read a row of data into an array
    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
    if ($rowData[0][9]=='')
    {
        echo 'No price for the product '.$rowData[0][1].'';
    }
    else 
    {
    $a = array('8', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5','6');
    $b = array($rowData[0][0], $rowData[0][2], $rowData[0][3],$rowData[0][5],$rowData[0][6],$rowData[0][8],$rowData[0][8]);
    $c = array_combine($a, $b);

    $slug = str_replace(" ", "-",$rowData[0][1]);
$slug = str_replace('"', "",$slug);
$slug = str_replace('/', "-",$slug);
    $stmt=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_products (name,slug,description,price)
                    VALUES (:name,:slug,:desc,:pret)");

$stmt->bindParam(":name",$rowData[0][1]);
$stmt->bindParam(":slug",$slug);
$stmt->bindParam(":desc",$rowData[0][10]);
$stmt->bindParam(":pret",$rowData[0][9]);

$stmt->execute();
$id_product=$dbh->lastInsertId();

$stmt=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_products_images_gallery (id_product,name,image,sort_order)
                    VALUES (:id,:name,:image,100)");

$stmt->bindParam(":id",$id_product);
$stmt->bindParam(":name",$rowData[0][4]);
$stmt->bindParam(":image",$slug);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt=$dbh->prepare("SELECT id_category from tbl_catalog_categories where name=:name");
$stmt->bindParam(":name",$rowData[0][2]);
$stmt->execute();
if($row=$stmt->fetch())
{
    $id_cat=$row['id_category'];
}   

$stmt=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_products_to_categories (id_category,id_product)
                    VALUES (:id_cat,:id_prod)");

$stmt->bindParam(":id_cat",$id_cat);
$stmt->bindParam(":id_prod",$id_product);

$stmt->execute();

foreach($c as $key => $value)
    {

        $stmt=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_products_attributes_values (id_product,id_attribute,attribute_value)
                    VALUES (:id_product,:id_attribute,:value)");
$stmt->bindParam(":id_product",$id_product);
$stmt->bindParam(":id_attribute",$key);
$stmt->bindParam(":value",$value);
$stmt->execute();
    }


}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if (empty($rowData[0][9]))` perhaps?

Or test for null as well as for empty strings - nulls are perfectly valid response from PHPExcel...

especially as

```
$rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
```

with it's null second argument is telling PHPExcel to return a null value if the cell simply doesn't exist in the spreadsheet

Though you can change the `rangeToArray()` call to

```
$rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, '', TRUE, FALSE);
```

to return an empty string instead of a null if the cell doesn't exist

Comment: it still goes on the else and returns the sql error, it inserts the first row and on the second row it should return the if echo but it goes on the else `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id_category' cannot be null in /home/r35345publ/anticariat.umbrellamedia.ro/admin/xls.php:99 Stack trace: #0 /home/r35345publ/anticariat.umbrellamedia.ro/admin/xls.php(99): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /home/r35345publ/anticariat.umbrellamedia.ro/admin/xls.php on line 99`

Comment: Well your check of cell [0][9] is just checking price, not category.... so what cell in each row contains the category?

Comment: it does not matter, if price is empty it should not go on the else where i have all the inserts.

Comment: Well the problem isn't with price.... it's with category.... do you have a cell containing a valid price that's triggering this error..... some basic debugging would hep you identify it

Comment: true, i just checked, you;re right, it does not even goest to the second row, thnx for oppening my eyes.

Comment: now it seems it does not get the value of that cell if it;s empty or null because now i getanother error `Uncaught PHPExcel_Exception: Invalid cell coordinate A in PHPExcel_Worksheet->rangeToArray('A:K', '', true, false) #3 {main} thrown in /home/r35345publ/anticariat.umbrellamedia.ro/admin/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php on line 558`

Comment: Looks like you're overwriting the value of `$row` somewhere.... perhaps `if($row=$stmt->fetch())` which will mess up the value of `$row` that you're using in your `for` loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148392/discussion-between-chris227-and-mark-baker).